# Meridium SQL Query Design

Tags: sql

I have a very specific problem where I have a field with a year in it. I need to be able to pull them out and have a query that makes a criteria to look at each row and select the year that is the largest but less than the year selected from a pick list, Because the joins I use has a lot of rows that need to be filtered out. Example I have ID in Column 1 as 1,2,3,4 ect down the rows. But I will have a few extra 1's say 5 rows with 1's in it. I want to filter out all the extra 1's that do not have the largest year in another column. So it needs to use the ID column to see which rows can be compared then only keep the rows with the largest year in the year column. There will be a bunch of groupings that need to be compared. Say all the 2's then 3's. Still keeping the ones with the largest year and filtering out ones that are less then the largest.

Below is kind of a base line query that also filters our rows that are no longer in service.

```
SELECT CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Equipment ID" "Equipment ID",  
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Pass/Fail" "Pass/Fail",   
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Failure Type" "Failure Type", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Desired Interval (MO)" "Desired Interval (MO)",
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Task Description" "Task Description", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Year" "Year", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Site" "Site",
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Device Type" "Device Type", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Execution Date" "Execution Date", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Eqpt Manufacturer" "Eqpt Manufacturer", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Eqpt Manufacturer Model Num" "Eqpt Manufacturer Model Num", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Eqpt Manufacturer Serial Nu" "Eqpt Manufacturer Serial Nu", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Decommission Year" "Decommission Year", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Commission Year" "Commission Year", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Equipment Key" "Equipment Key", 
CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Test Key" "Test Key"

FROM (! 'Personal[cmgray1]\Queries\CDFT Updated\CDFT Test Results Primary Multi Year Pre Non-Test' ) CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M

WHERE (((CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Year" <= CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Decommission Year" 
AND CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Year" >= CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Commission Year") 
AND CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Decommission Year" >= (? :s :caption='Year Selection' :id=DecomYear :l='2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020' :excl) 
AND CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Commission Year" <= (? :s :caption='Year Selection' :id=DecomYear :l='2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020' :excl)) 
OR (CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Decommission Year" IS NULL AND CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Commission Year" IS NULL) 
OR (CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Year" >= CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Commission Year" 
AND CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Decommission Year" IS NULL 
AND CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Commission Year" <= (? :s :caption='Year Selection' :id=DecomYear :l='2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020' :excl)) 
OR (CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Year" <= CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Decommission Year" 
AND CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Decommission Year" >= (? :s :caption='Year Selection' :id=DecomYear :l='2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020' :excl) 
AND CDFT_Test_Results_Primary_M."Commission Year" IS NULL))
```

As you can see below if you group by Equipment ID you get multiple years under Task Description. I would like to be able to pick the largest of the group set and filter out the rest. For example the 2009 should be filtered out and the 2013 point remain for devices of similar Equipment ID.

[image]

Comment: Even an idea of the direction I should look at would be fine. I have been stumped on this for a while now.

Comment: Can you read your own query in that format? I couldn't. Please format it in a readable way and reduce it to the core problem.

Comment: which rdbms all 3?  If all 3 you can typically take out oracle and sql-server because mysql will be one of the more limiting from function specific methods.  Next I agree with juergen format the query so it is readable.  I started to but nope its on you to do.  Next you are asking for advice from people that more than likely know the functions of a system so we don't really need the images to tell us what they are. lastly example data and desired result should be included.  However it sounds like you need to rethink the description to Max Year Less than input variable cte with row_number

Comment: Updated as per Matt and Juergen D comments

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a sub query to group by the ID then used the MAX function on that column. Then I used a join function back to the original query to get exactly what I needed.